# Lua: "Secure cache"

Tags: lua

How can I make a script that will check if some functions have been redefined? This can be usefull for games like roblox, fivem etc.
Its usefull because cheaters can modify important functions, such as AC functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
function ThisIsProtected(...)
    local args = {...}
    for k, v in pairs(args) do
        print(k, v)
    end
end

local function CreateCache(Namespace)
    local Cache = {}
    for k, v in pairs(Namespace) do
        if type(v) ~= "string" then
            Cache[k] = tostring(v)
        end
    end

    return Cache
end

local function CheckCache(Namespace, CacheTable)
    for k, v in pairs(CacheTable) do
        if Namespace[v] ~= CacheTable[v] then
            print("Something is modified :/")
            return true
        end
    end

    return false
end


local SecureCache = CreateCache(_G)
while true do
    Wait(60000)
    if CheckCache(SecureCache) then
        os.exit()
    end
end

-- Cheater/Bad person trying to redefine function
function ThisIsProtected(...)
    print("AHAHAHHAHAHAHHA")
end
```

Comment: `function CheckCache() end`  I just disabled your mechanism by redefining a function ;)

Comment: :/ now im sad            totally didn't add spaces so i could send this message

Comment: Did you even try this code before you posted an answer with it? It has multiple errors that prevent it from working at all, even without counting Piglet's trivial bypass (and several other bypasses).